# How to start animation on every click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gallery

I am making a gallery with thumbnails. It works but I want to make an image transition, and I want it to fades in. In this case it fades in but only for the first image. The next images show up without any animation.

```
$('.picture').click(function() {
    $("#screen img").attr('src', $(this).attr('src')).animate({
        height: "400px"
    }, 2000);
});
```

And also, can someone tell me how to position the image in the div to be centrally placed using the width and the height of the div and the image? I don't want to use plugin for the gallery, so I would appreciate your help very much.

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle? We can't do much with only javascript code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/53Zc8/1/ Here is a jsfiddle, but I have no idea why this isn't working here, it is working in my program..

Comment: You didn't require the jquery library in your fiddle, that's why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To maintain your current transition try

```
var $simg = $("#screen img");
$('.picture').click(function () {
    var $img = $(this);
    if ($simg.height() == 0) {
        $("#screen img").attr('src', $(this).attr('src')).animate({
            height: "400px"
        }, 2000);
    } else {
        $("#screen img").animate({
            height: "0"
        }, function () {
            $(this).attr('src', $img.attr('src')).animate({
                height: "400px"
            }, 2000)
        });
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Q7Vn9/), [using fade animation](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Q7Vn9/2/)

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly! By the way, can I align my picture in the center of the div with animation? If it is about pictures with different widths and heights, can it be done somehow?